# No import Insellisense for custom Typescript npm package on Verdaccio

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, intellisense, npm-publish

We've a [Verdaccio](https://github.com/verdaccio/verdaccio) server as internal NPM registry. I developed a Typescript library, which is published to Verdaccio. In the `index.ts` of the module, all classes are exported:

```
export { SSO } from './sso';
export { AdUserInfo } from './AdUserInfo';
```

This makes it nice to import them like `import { SSO, AdUserInfo } from 'my-module-name'` in a Typescript application that consumes my module. It's working fine, but I don't get any intellisense like I'm used to in other modules.

An example would be [ldapjs](http://ldapjs.org/): There is a class called `Client`for the ldap client. When I want to use this class without writing a manual `import` statement, intellisense shows me the class exists in `ldaps`

[image]

Here I only need to press [Return] and the corresponding import statement is added like this:

```
import { Client } from 'ldaps';
```

This is not working in my custom module, although I export all the classes there and typings are generated by setting `"declaration": true` in `tsconfig.json`.
My classes are found when I manually import them like `import { SSO } from 'my-module-name';` only intellisense doesn't suggest them like in the screenshot for `ldapjs`.

#### Why is this not working?

Comment: Does your custom module include a `types` (or `typings`) property in its `package.json` that points to the module's declaration file?  See an example here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/publishing.html

Comment: @NathanFriend Yes, I already saw this article, my `package.json` contains `"main": "dist/index.js"` and corresponding type definition as `"types": "dist/index.d.ts"` where `dist` is defined as `outDir` in `tsconfig.json`.